# What patterns of local storage I/O are well addressed by dispatch_io?

Tags: grand-central-dispatch

I'm a big fan of Grand Central Dispatch, and I've recently been looking at the `dispatch_io_*` family of calls.  It's easy to see how this API could be useful for network I/O (slow, high latency). That said, the existence of `dispatch_io_create_with_path` sort of implies use on a local filesystem.  (Yes, I get know that a path could also point to a resource on a remote network file system, but anyway...) In playing around with it, I've observed that using `dispatch_io_*` seems to carry considerable overhead compared to using simple blocking I/O calls (`read`, `write`, etc.). This slowdown seems to be primarily from the kernel synchronization primitives used as blocks are marshaled back and forth between queues. In the sample workload I've been playing with (very much I/O bound), the slowdown can be as bad as 10 times. For one thing, it looks like `dispatch_io` would never be a win for chatty (small granule) I/O.

I posit that in the common case of a single machine with a single, local, physical storage volume, I/O requests will effectively be serialized at the device level. From there, I found myself with these two thoughts:

- If your workload is CPU-bound, then by definition, you can already read/write data faster than you can process it.
- If your workload is I/O-bound (in this situation -- one, local, physical volume) using `dispatch_io` can't make your disk give you data any faster.

From there, I thought that maybe the sweet spot for this API might be in the middle -- a workload that teeters between being CPU-bound and I/O-bound, but at this point I've kinda thought myself into a corner, so I figured I'd ask StackOverflow.

I'll accept the first answer that describes a "real world" workflow with these preconditions (i.e. single machine, single local physical disk) for which using `dispatch_io` would yield a significant performance improvement.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The main use case for dispatch I/O from a local filesystem is asynchronous IO of larger files, or of many files read/written concurrently (particularly if the contents of the files can be processed incrementally).

Dispatch I/O from local filesystems was optimized for throughput over latency (e.g. it performs chunking and advisory reads ahead of the actual IO syscalls to optimize pipelining & throughput on the IO path through the kernel and driver).

Given the asynchronous execution of the IO syscalls on background threads, dispatch IO will never beat the latency of a tiny file IO performed with a blocking syscall, particularly when no other IO activity is ongoing.

The GCD session from WWDC11 covers dispatch I/O in some detail and has an example comparison of throughput improvements achieved over straight read() syscalls for reading many files at various sizes.